# pytorch - combining loss functions from multiple nodes

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a network with output from multiple nodes and each has a loss function, loss1, loss2, loss3..
The final loss function is loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3.
When loss.backward() is called. All nodes will get backpropagated. But my question is: Do I need to scale the output value of loss1, loss2, and loss3 into a similar range? What's the logic behind it?
For example, if loss1 produces values in the range of 10k while loss2 and loss3 both in the range of 1-10, does that mean node associated with loss1 will be more significant in overall training? Same optimizer is used here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit-The second answer:

I think the important thing here is loss function metrics. Do these loss functions of yours depend on the same metric or not? That's the important question. If these depend on the same metric and if these losses are calculated from the same features, then it's already scaled, and you are good to go with the summation of them. But if they do not depend on the same features, you can sum them with weighting according to your feature importance preferences. Or, if your losses are depending on different matrices, this means they are not returning the same information, and their gradient update won't be the same.

Since there are so many different matrices:
[image]

and since optimization algorithms like Gradient Descent depend on derivatives of the loss function with respect to its weights:

[image]

Logically updates of gradients differ according to your metric.

As an example, there is a good graph that shows L1 & L2 metrics with their derivatives:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So logically, I think giving separately provides a better situation if your metrics are different; if not, I guess you are right, and it doesn't matter.

Comment: So how would you go on to scale the losses? And if you do so, wouldn't you require more epochs (longer training) since the losses have "shrunk"?

Comment: I think I couldn't get your question. Since losses are not features to feed into neural networks it wouldn't affect the num of epochs. We are summing losses in an optimized situation which means a situation that we think the algorithm has already found the minimal achievable loss.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I a bit confused though. The example you provided is about how features scale will affect the loss. For my case, the inputs are based on the same sets of features as it's the same network. The outputs, which are used to calculate the losses, are different. Hence the losses are of different scale. What is the effect of summing up these losses instead of backpropagating them separately?

Comment: I'm not so sure about the difference but if your losses are depending on different matrices like loss1>" mean squared error", loss2>" mean absolute error"; summing them might give your network wrong information since they aren't calculated in the same way. I think probably backpropagating them separately would be better.

Comment: I did read from a few sources that summing them up before backpropagating is same as backpropagating separately. However, I'm still not sure how the scale of each loss affects the learning. By right each loss should be optimized whether we sum them or not.

Comment: Can you provide the links that you've seen this information?  My first answer became irrelevant after talking I'm updating that and giving a new one according to my last comment about different matrices and why that affects. I will use reasoning rather than pure knowledge so it's open to discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the second answer. All 3 metrics are different. Maybe I will dig further on how pytorch's backpropagation work. From my testing, there is indeed a difference between loss1.backward(), loss2.backward(), loss3.backward() and (w1*loss1+w2*loss2+w3*loss3).backward().

Comment: I just want to add that you can not optimize three losses at once the way you are describing. If you call .backward() on loss1 the gradients are calculated w.r.t. that loss. If you call .backward() on your second loss, all gradients will be re-calculated. If you want a combination of losses, as you often see in literature, you need to sum them all together (like you did). Adding weights to the losses is then indeed important because each loss has a different range. The weights in the linear equation decide the contributions of each loss.

Comment: @dljve that's the part I'm confused. I read from a few places that for pytorch even you sum them up, the gradients of each loss will be optimized, i.e. the system will try to minimize each loss. Hence in an ideal situation, all losses will be near 0 in the end and weights don't really affect the results but how fast you can reach there. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Richie I don't think what you are saying is completely correct. There is one loss function at the end of your network, and the gradient will be calculated w.r.t. this loss function. If you calculate your weight gradient w.r.t. 3 separate losses you need 3 separate updates. And one update might minimize one loss but not the other. This is why the correct way is to use a sum of the three losses. Technically this doesn't mean that each loss will go to 0, it means their total sum will be minimized. One loss could be large if that means the other two are really low.

Comment: @Richie Also keep in mind the ranges of each loss. For example, negative log loss is ideal when it is <<0, while dice for instance is ideal when it's 0. So you need to give them a weight factor that decides their contribution.

Comment: @dljve Thanks for the reply. How about summing negative log loss with positive loss? Will the optimization try to reduce the overall sum to 0? In that case, the result will not be ideal for each of these losses.

Comment: @Richie Gradient descent follows the slope downhill in the loss landscape until it reaches a local or global minimum. This minimum could lie at any value, depending on the range of your loss function. Gradient descent tries to minimize whatever loss you have (so to make it as small as possible). It doesn't have to stop at 0. If your first loss function has a range between -50 and 50, and your second loss function has a range between 0 and 1, you could scale your first loss to the scale of the second loss: (loss1+50)/100. The way you scale your losses decided their contribution.

Comment: @Richie I think it's always useful to write out my loss formula on paper and figure out how each part of the formula contributes to the total loss value.